# What all can be the third arguement in for_each in C++?

Tags: c++

What all can be the third parameter in for_each in C++ ?
I read its unary function but the code which I encountered had object of some class as third arguement.

Comment: Can you post the code you encountered?

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) you can find a nice description of this function.

Comment: You need to look for Functors ( function objects )

Comment: The third argument tells `for_each` what to do.

Comment: @Banex : I cant post the exact code. still I can convey the structure of code . Hope ths helps.. 
Point point(a,word.offset());
for_each(&buffer[0],&buffer[word.length()],point);

Answer (score 3):

The third argument can be a function object that is an object that can be used in the postfix expression of function call.

From the C++ Standard (20.9 Function objects)

> 1 A function object type is an object type (3.9) that can be the type
>   of the postfix-expression in a function call (5.2.2, 13.3.1.1).231 A
>   function object is an object of a function object type. In the places
>   where one would expect to pass a pointer to a function to an
>   algorithmic template (Clause 25), the interface is specified to accept
>   a function object. **This not only makes algorithmic templates work
>   with pointers to functions, but also enables them to work with
>   arbitrary function objects**

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    struct A
    {
        void operator()( int x ) const { std::cout << x << ' '; }
    };

    std::for_each( a, a + N, A() );
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Here is temporary object `A()` of type `struct A` is a function object because it can be used in the postfix expression of function call due to the definition of the function call operator `in struct A`.

For example you can write

```
std::cout << A()( a[0] ) std::endl;
```

or

```
A obj;
std::cout << obj( a[0] ) std::endl;
```

As you see expression `obj( a[0] )` looks like a function call.

Comment: Can you please provide me some link for better understanding.

Comment: @Arpit Jaiswal I myself do not use such kind of links so I do not know them. But in any case you should read about the function call operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

From [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) :

> ```
> template<class InputIterator, class Function>
> Function for_each (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function fn);
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `first`, `last`
>   Input iterators to the initial and final positions in
>   a sequence. The range used is `[first,last)`, which contains all the
>   elements between first and last, including the element pointed by
>   first but not the element pointed by last.
>
> `fn`
>   Unary function that
>   accepts an element in the range as argument.
>   This can either be a function pointer or a move constructible function object.
>   Its return value, if any, is ignored.